# Long press gesture on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have been trying to setup a long press gesture recognizer on my uitableview. I have been able to get it to register, however it seems to give me incorrect information for the associated row. My tableview works as expected with a  normal click,  it passes the `indexPath.row` and i am able to get the correct record from an array of `people` associated to that row. However on using the code below, the indexPath.row seems to be inconsistent and selects rows above and below, and then when scrolled it picks random records on long press.

```
func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            let person = people[indexPath.row]
            print("\(person.name)")
            ///////works but erratic responses//////////
        }
    }
}

//// in view did load i have this


    let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PeopleVC.longPress(_:)))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

Comment: Maybe you should use tableView whereas controller main view (will not solve the problem if the controller is a UITableViewController) : `longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)` whereas `longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)`

Comment: you should try to put this code in uitableviewcell and then you should made delegate for that.

Comment: Thanks, totally makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
```

To this:

```
let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
```

You're looking for a gesture inside your `UITableView` not your `UIView`.

Comment: Works. Thanks couldn't quite debug that one myself.